# Some values persist while refresing the html page

Tags: javascript

while refreshing my html page (it holds some external javaScript code), some variables values persist..
i.e. after refreshing the html page, variables values which are used for displaying on the html page persist and displays for a while..

through your views with some solutions on the same.

thanks,
regards
Naveen.

Comment: What do you mean "for a while"? Are the variable values being set based on form field values?

Comment: There is not enough information to help. If the page is refreshed, the previous JavaScript context goes away.

Comment: I have used the javaScript code for maintaining a clock and to sync. it with the real time streaming, that streaming is done by the server the clock will help me in enabling and disabling the forward seek on the basis of the real time and the clock time....

Comment: This clock value persist when i refresh the page and play the same or different file for a while and then all goes perfectly .... this small blinking is noticeable,, but when i refresh the page 2-3 or more time it get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The values that are persisting are probably session variables, those are stored on the server side and tied to the user client. You should look into resetting session variables when the page is reloaded.

Comment: hi burgar, I am not using any of the servlet or jsp which holds seesion variables in javascript, its just a clock for synchronizing with server, which runs on the client machine. This clock variables value persist when i abruptly refresh the page and play the file again.